# How can I configure Windows 10 to prefer bash in my PATH over the WSL Bash Launcher

Tags: windows-10, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed msys2 on my system, which provides a program named "bash" in `C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe`. I've also installed WSL on my system, which provides a launcher named "bash" in `C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe`.

I generally have more use for msys2's bash than WSL's bash, so I'd like to configure Windows 10 to use the former when I type in "bash" in the Run box. I've tried placing `C:\msys64\usr\bin` before `C:\Windows\system32` in the PATH variable. However, Windows seems to always prefer WSL bash, and I can't find another way to change this behaviour.

So, is there another way?

Comment: Uninstall WSL? Or are there reasons for you to keep WSL if you're already using an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I've pinned shortcuts in my toolbar to both bash's.  One points to C:\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe and the other to C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-lxss-bash_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_50af37c8f560d163\bash.exe